# Where can i find open medical datasets in HL7/FHIR format?

Tags: dataset, bigdata, hl7-fhir, medical, opendata

I need open data in HL7/FHIR format for a big data project. I try many portals, but until now i didn't find anything interesting. I'm looking for imaging, EHR and biosignals of any type (ECG, EEG, EMG ecc..)

list of web site links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find artificial FHIR data from tools like Synthea.  You won't usually find *real* patient data available on any 'open' interface - because it's considered protected information.  To get access, you'll need to make an arrangement with a specific data source, and the data will need to go through a de-identification process specific to your intended use.